# Remove build in Apache httpd on macOS (OSX)

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server, launchd, launchctl

I have a Mac Mini running a private server from home.
It is running macos High Sierra (osx) and and previous used "Apple Server" to manage my websites (using the build in apache httpd). But since Apple decided to give the Apple Server a big cut in features, and leaving it useless as a product for me, I had to find another solution.

I have searched to net for how to get rid of the build in httpd. All guides just say stop apache an unload it for launchd. That works fine, until a reboot, the build in apache is back again. Something is loading it back into launchd. Eventough i have disabled it "com.apple.server.httpd" is still loaded and running  again after a reboot.
And it seems to be starting before my new NGINX, which then fails to start as port 80 and 443 has already been taken by the build in apache.

I found that there is also a "com.apple.serviceproxy" which is also related to the httpd, so I also tried to stop and unload that. But both httpd and serviceproxy are back again after a reboot.

So my question is how do I get rid of "com.apple.server.httpd" and "com.apple.serviceproxy" for all. I don't need then and I don't want it running, I want then to be gone for all time.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC you can permanently stop it from launching by executing the following:

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

It will still be installed but shouldn't start anymore.

Comment: Thats what I did alot of times, but it somehow reloads it self when restarted. (By the way that command will unload your own installed apache, not the build in, as the build in is called "com.apple.server.httpd".